# Distribuir aplicações com Mysql

Tags: mysql

Alguém sabe como distribuir a aplicação e banco mysql junto?

Estou usando o Innosetup, até consigo fazer a instalação do mysql, startar o serviço mas quando vou conectar ele dá erro dizendo que não posso conectar. Veja o código do inno:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "ServerSisEscola"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ServerSisEscola"
#define MyAppURL "http://"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{6AF944A0-16EF-4099-8AA7-6FC0F023D9E5}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=C:\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: brazilianportuguese; MessagesFile: compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl

[Files]
Source: D:\tcc Sis_escola\Sistema_Escola\Sistema_Escola\bin\Debug\Banco\*; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: D:\tcc Sis_escola\Sistema_Escola\Sistema_Escola\bin\Debug\Banco\IniciarServico.bat; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}

[Tasks]
Name: ServidorSisEscola; Description: Servidor Sistema Escola; Flags: exclusive
[Run]
Filename: {app}\IniciarServico.bat; Flags: waituntilidle
```

Depois disso ele Abre um .bat para configurar:

```
cd bin
mysqld --install Mysql_SistemaEscola --defaults-file="C:\ServerSisEscola\my.ini")
net start Mysql_SistemaEscola
cd bin
mysql -u root -p 3308 -h localhost SistemaEscola.sql <SistemaEscola.sql
```

Eu copiei toda a pasta do mysql para o diretório de minha aplicação segundo [esse tutorial](http://fivewin.com.br/index.php?/topic/21305-instalador-com-o-mysql/) mas não deu certo, não consigo conectar.

Comment: Coloca o erro exato do MySQL na sua pergunta que fica mais fácil descobrir qual o problema.

Comment: Esse é o erro

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: Você mudou a porta do MySQL pra `3308`? A padrão é `3306`.

Comment: Certo. Mudei para 3306 e contia o erro. Eu esqueci de mencionar isso

Comment: Tem certeza que o MySQL foi iniciado? Dê uma olhada no log de eventos, pode ser que algo tenha dado errado. Por favor, coloque seu arquivo `my.ini`.

Comment: Outra coisa que percebi agora: `-p` é o parâmetro para pedir que o password seja digitado. Para especificar a porta você tem que usar `-P [PORTA]` (P maíusculo) ou `--port [PORTA]`

Comment: olá  Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira, muito obrigado pelo retorno. Não cabe todo arquivo.
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306


#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:\ServerSisEscola\bin"

#Path to the database root
datadir="C:\ServerSisEscola\Data\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não conecta porque teu banco não foi criado, o MySQL foi instalado mas ele não criou teu banco porque existe um erro no arquivo .bat na linha:

```
"mysql -u root -p 3308 -h localhost SistemaEscola.sql < SistemaEscola.sql"
```

Deveria ser:

```
mysql -uroot -pTUASENHA -h localhost < SistemaEscola.sql
```

ou

```
mysql --user=root --password=TUASENHA -h localhost < SistemaEscola.sql
```

E no SistemaEscola.sql deve existir um:

```
create database NOMEDOTEUBANCO;
```

Apenas se o banco já estivesse previamente criado poderia ser usado:

```
mysql -uroot -pTUASENHA -h localhost NOMEDOTEUBANCO < SistemaEscola.sql
```